# Is there a price for raising the number of concurrent consumers in spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp

Spring AMQP says

> Raising the number of concurrent consumers is recommended in order to
>   scale the consumption of messages coming in from a queue.

While performance testing my application I'm noticing that raising the concurrent consumer relative to number of items in the queue makes the application faster. But I wonder if there is a price paid while raising the number of consumers? By that I mean does it drain resources on the server if I drastically raise the number of concurrent consumers?

Ideally i'm trying to find out what is the max number of concurrent consumers I can set?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this concurrency sample isn't different from other Java multy-threaded scenarios.

The best answers to this question you can finde from `Java Concurrency In Practice` Book.

And there is a classical formula to determine the best concurrecny:

[image]